# How to mock pydantic BaseModel that expects a Response object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pydantic

I'm writing tests for my API client. I need to mock the `get` function so that it won't make any requests. So instead of returning a `Response` object I want to return a `MagicMock`. But then pydantic raises `ValidationError` because it is going to the model.

I have the following pydantic model:

```
class Meta(BaseModel):
    raw: Optional[str]
    response: Optional[Response]

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

which raises:

```
>   ???
E   pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for OneCallResponse
E   meta -> response
E     instance of Response expected (type=type_error.arbitrary_type; expected_arbitrary_type=Response)
```

The one solution would be to add `Union` with `MagicMock` but I really don't want to change the code for tests. That is not the way.

```
class Meta(BaseModel):
    raw: Optional[str]
    response: Optional[Union[Response, MagicMock]]

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
```

Any ideas how to patch/mock it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a `MagicMock`/`Mock`, you can create a subclass of `Response` for tests, then patch `requests.get` to return an instance of that subclass.

This lets you:

- Maintain the type of your mock as `Response` (making pydantic happy)
- Control most of the expected response behavior for tests
- Avoid polluting app code with test code (Yes, the "*one solution would be to add `Union` with `MagicMock`*" is *definitely* not the way.)

(I'm going to assume the `Response` is from the **requests** library. If it isn't, then appropriately adjust the attributes and methods to be mocked. The idea is the same.)

```
# TEST CODE

import json
from requests import Response
from requests.models import CaseInsensitiveDict

class MockResponse(Response):
    def __init__(self, mock_response_data: dict, status_code: int) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        # Mock attributes or methods depending on the use-case.
        # Here, mock to make .text, .content, and .json work.

        self._content = json.dumps(mock_response_data).encode()
        self.encoding = "utf-8"
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.headers = CaseInsensitiveDict(
            [
                ("content-length", str(len(self._content))),
            ]
        )
```

Then, in tests, you just need to instantiate a `MockResponse` and tell `patch` to return that:

```
# APP CODE

import requests
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class Meta(BaseModel):
    raw: Optional[str]
    response: Optional[Response]

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

def get_meta(url: str) -> Meta:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    meta = Meta(raw=resp.json()["status"], response=resp)
    return meta
```

```
# TEST CODE

from unittest.mock import patch

def test_get_meta():
    mocked_response_data = {"status": "OK"}
    mocked_response = MockResponse(mocked_response_data, 200)

    with patch("requests.get", return_value=mocked_response) as mocked_get:
        meta = get_meta("http://test/url")

    mocked_get.call_count == 1
    assert meta.raw == "OK"
    assert meta.response == mocked_response
    assert isinstance(meta.response, Response)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Gino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69060231), I would suggest creating a new class, but subclassing `MagicMock` and not `Response` or any class mentioned in your pydantic model. Then override the magic `__class__` method:

```py
class MockRequest(MagicMock):
    @property
    def __class__(self):
        return Response
```

Then patch this object as the return value for `requests.get` or whatever your code needs.
So:

1. You get a `MagicMock` object in your test code, benefiting from its `spec`cing and other abilities.
2. Pydantic gets an object that passes the `isinstance` check.